# Glitchy colors in minecraft that have nothing to do with graphics card

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Now this doesn't have anything to do with my graphics card. This only happens in Minecraft. I use Windows 7, the problem starts and stops randomly. It only affects in game, not the menu, only the part where you actually run around.

I played around with the options, but nothing seemed to fix it. The colors turn from creepily shaded red and blue grey, and colors that look like an acid trip. The shading freaks out and teleports to different sides of blocks in a pattern that looks almost like the biggest QR code in the universe. If I dig down one block, its red and blue. This isn't caused by the 3D anaglyph; I always have it off.

[image: Ive taken this while paused but this is what the ground looks like from this angle]

Comment: Betting you turned on anaglyph in the graphics options

Comment: Might have something to do with the Super Secret Settings...?

Comment: @rivermont-WillB. Super secret settings shouldn't persist between play sessions, and red/blue/grey sounds like 3d anaglyph.

Comment: Its not 3d anaglyph.

Comment: I've edited the question to try to clear it up, but I don't think the screenshot is detailed enough for people to help.  Do you have mods?

Comment: Or a better/larger screenshot?

Comment: I notice this question covers everything from the duplicate. However, Asker from the dupe appears to have gone awal, and the other question is still open. Perhaps we should be trying to resolve this question, on which we can mark the other as a duplication of this one?

Comment: I'm sorry for the problem of being very vague and not giving the required information for all to understand. I should be uploading a screenshot in a bit.    (nevermind. The problem went away by itself as I just said "it starts whenever it wants and ends whenever it wants") Now I cant actually screenshot it. and another thing. I was gone becuase I went offline due to it being late at night.

Comment: And just to clarify. The way minecraft looks when this bug activates is actually very creepy compared to 3d anaglyph being turned on.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you turned on something called **3D Anaglyph**. This is for people with those red-blue glasses, so they can see their Minecraft world in three dimensions. To turn it off, go into `Settings > Video Settings > 3D Anaglyph` and turn it off.

Comment: Nope. its not 3d anaglyph, i've already had it off and im never turning it on.